# Is there a way to test my software on a mac without buying a mac?

Tags: macos, virtualization

I need to test my web application on a Mac/Safari - especially stuff related to keyboard handling. I couldn't find any service that simply lets me connect to a hosted OSX instance. Is there something like this?

IOW, is there a way to test my software on a mac without buying a mac?

Comment: Have you considered Safari on Windows? What do you need that is different between the two?

Comment: wow. this is the first time a question of mine is migrated _into_ SO from another site. I guess I'll never quite know what belongs here..

Comment: @ughoavgfhw the keyboard is different, and that's the problematic stuff for me. Having different keys and key-codes, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "keyboard handling" you mean typing into standard controls the risk is probably quite low. It also depends on whether you will need to provide support for the system as well: it might be frustrating to debug an issue a customer has without having somewhat similar equipment. The keyboard layout is all different to Windows and Linux and even frequently used characters such as @ and \ may be challenging - of course it all depends on how well programmed the controls are.

So to put it short, if I were you I'd spend 200$ on an used iMac running whatever OSX version just to be sure. 200$ isn't much compared to tens or hundreds of hours of debugging. With that investment you can also verify that the layout and other functionality works ok on Safari and OSX.

Comment: This solution has the disadvantage of not being portable. e.g. I can't give my laptop to a remote tester to use. Whereas with a hosted virtual machine..

Answer (score 2):

Can't say I've used them but you could look at [cloud4mac.com](http://www.cloud4mac.com/)

Comment: Total Mac newb here, so tell me please, is the server edition the same as the desktop edition in terms of UI and web browser? meaning, can I feel confident my web application would work properly on a Mac desktop/laptop after having tested on the server?

Comment: Generally speaking, a user session on MacOS Server is identical to a user session on MacOS client. As long as you don't use any weird keyboard combinations with Ctrl, Alt and/or Cmd, you should be fine even over some kind of remote session, but some combinations might not work very well over such a connection.

Answer (score 1):

You can run OS X inside a VM fairly easily these days.  You don't get 3D acceleration but it sounds like you don't need it for your testing anyway.

Comment: But if so then why aren't there hosting providers offering this as a service? I really don't want to go into the whole mess of installing and maintaining this system myself.

Comment: Presumably the reward would not be worth the presumably high risk of being made an example of for breaking the EULA. See: Psystar.